# Creating drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've spent some time trying to find an elegant and cross browser solution but was unable.  I'm trying to dynamically create a drop down.  Here is my html:

```
...
<span id="currencies">
</span>
...
```

In my script I'm trying to do the following:

- Create a select element
- Put, say, 4 options into it - 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', and 'DDD'
- Append the select element to $('#currencies')

I am assuming that for the code to be cross browser it should be written using jQuery.  When I say elegant I mean possibly trying to avoid too much markup, for example, something like this:

```
// THIS IS NOT A WORKING CODE
$('#currencies').appendSelect().addOption('AAA', 'AAA').addOption('BBB', 'BBB')...
```

Maybe somebody has some tip.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do it like this:

```
var $s = $('<select/>').appendTo($('#currencies'));
$.each(['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD'],function(i,text){
    $s.append($('<option/>',{value:text,html:text}));
});
```

Comment: Andy, thank you, I think this is very a nice code.  Just one question, why did you put the dollar sign in front of the variable name, is this like a jQuery convention or something?

Comment: @SBel i'd say it's quasi convention. It helps to quickly distinguish jquery from regular variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must make A string

`var string1='<option>AAA</option><option>BBB</option>.........</option>'`

Then

`$('#currencies').html(string1);`

will do the Job for You